Lebl, Jiří. Basic Analysis I: Introduction to Real Analysis, Volume 1 - Solution Manual
This is not a math problem/question.
I was hoping if any one of y'all know where I could find the solution manual for the book: Basic Analysis I: Introduction to Real Analysis. I am self-studying Real Analysis this summer and the solution manual (even if it only contains just the final answers) would be super helpful.
So please let me know,
Thanks in advance!

Hi, after a quick look on Lebl’s website, it seems there is no solution manual. The author says: ‘ There is no solutions manual for the exercises. This situation is intentional. There is an unfortunately large number of problems with solutions out there already. Part of learning how to do proofs is to learn how to recognize your proof is correct. Looking at someone else's proof is a far less effective way of checking your proof than actually checking your proof.’ That being said, if you get really stuck you can always ask on Stack Exchange. Hope that helps!
